AC-to-DC rectifier and DC-to-DC converter
I am currently doing an assignment featuring an AC-DC EV Charger topology as shown below.

I have obtained answers for (a) and (b). However, I am unable to derive the equation exactly as given in the answer scheme. Below is the equation I have derived:

However, the answer given by my lecturer is different for Io value, where

Even after simplifying my equation to its simplest form, I was still unable to obtain the given equation. Is there an error in my calculation somewhere or is the answer given incorrect? Any clarification would be highly appreciated.
